# Phrase Request: "electronics for military use"

Tags: phrase-requests

I am translating a CV into English. One of the mentioned companies is (directly translated):

> An international company operating in the industry of electronics for military use

I could write this and leave it at that, but I wondered whether there are better ways to express it.  *Defense Contractor* comes to mind:

> An international defense contractor for the electronics industry

**Is there a better way to translate this sentence?**

Comment: Your second version is fine. *In 1999 British Aerospace and Marconi Electronic Systems merged to form BAE Systems, Europe's largest [**defense contractor***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=marconi+electronics+%22defense+contractor%22)

Comment: "a leading electronic systems supplier to the defense sector".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> An international military electronics company

This seems to be the most direct translation. I would avoid using the phrase "defense contractor", since that specifies a relationship between the company and a government (typically the United States government), which might not be the case here.

Comment: I do like your version, but at a first read it sounded like it was a military company in the electronics industry. I'll clarify with the CV owner whether there was really a contract with a government agency too.

Answer (score 2):

/An international company operating in the industry of electronics for military use/ should read:
An international company in the military electronics industry.
The word operating sounds like a construction used in a Romance language; it is not needed in English. Typically, in English, one says: an x company in the y industry. Military electronics is an industrial sector.

Comment: Correct, translating from Italian. I copied it out directly to give out as much info as possible.

Comment: Yes, I know, I am also a translator working with three Romance languages. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

I think your second sentence needs to be rearranged:

> an electronics contractor for the defence sector

Your version suggests that the company provides security services to the electronics industry.

You could go with:

> a contractor for the defence electronics sector

Or, most succinctly:

> a defence electronics contractor

Answer (score 1):

Honestly I would stick with your first sentence. Also, ensure the correct spelling of defense/defence for your target if you choose to go that route. American English would use the s, while British English would use the c.